# Bind9: TTL 604800 exceeds configured max-zone-ttl 86400

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I'm running bind 9.16.33 nameserver on debian.  It's been working fine, but all of a sudden several domains stopped working.  The named logs show:

```
dns_master_load: ki9.us.db:3: TTL 604800 exceeds configured max-zone-ttl 86400
dns_master_load: ki9.us.db:3: out of range
zone ki9.us/IN: loading from master file ki9.us.db failed: out of range
zone ki9.us/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

This happened all of a sudden in the middle of the night, not after making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

At some point since the last dnssec key resigning, I had added some new records with a TTL of 604800.  The `max-zone-ttl` is a part of the `dnssec-policy`.  According to the [v9.18 docs](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_18_6/reference.html#namedconf-statement-max-zone-ttl):

> This specifies the maximum permissible TTL value for the zone. When a zone file is loaded, any record encountered with a TTL higher than max-zone-ttl causes the zone to be rejected.
>
> This ensures that when rolling to a new DNSKEY, the old key will remain available until RRSIG records have expired from caches. The max-zone-ttl option guarantees that the largest TTL in the zone is no higher than a known and predictable value.

So the problem didn't show up until the keys were rotated.  I had been using the default `dnssec-policy`, which apparently has a `max-zone-ttl` value of 86400.

Instead of changing my records, I decided to increase the max value in `named.conf.local`.  This is what it was when it wasn't working:

```
zone "ki9.us" {
    dnssec-policy default;
    ....
}
```

And I changed it to this:

```
dnssec-policy "bigttl" {
  max-zone-ttl 604800;
}
zone "ki9.us" {
    dnssec-policy bigttl;
    ....
}
```

And then restarted bind and it was solved.  The new "bigttl" policy only had to be defined once and then it could be referenced in the zone section of each of my domains.